# Buggy joins on CodeIgniter ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, join, left-join

Recently, I have noticed again an unbelievable logical mistake in CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord Library.

The problem occurs, when I try to use "AND" in a join.

Example Query:

```
$this -> db -> join(
    'predict',
    "predict.id_predict = portion.id_predict AND event.id_event = 5",
    'left'
);
```

Result:

```
LEFT JOIN `predict` ON
    `predict`.`id_predict` = `portion`.`id_predict`
    AND event.id_event = 5
```

But it should be more likely:

```
LEFT JOIN `predict` ON (
     `predict`.`id_predict` = `portion`.`id_predict`
     AND `event`.`id_event` = 5
)
```

Is there any way to prevent this mistake?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/152221/ still suffer from eyesight after checking this ?

Comment: Is the issue the missing backticks on the second clause, or the missing brackets? I'm wondering if my eyesight is playing up too, since I'd imagine both forms would return the same result.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Corrupt/wrong data returned? An error? The back ticks should not make a difference to the query but allow you to use non-standard identifier names. Even though `event.id_event` has no back ticks it should not affect the outcome. The extra parenthesis are not needed either to have a valid SQL statement, although it may help convey your intent to someone else reading the statement.

Comment: IMO the `join` should only contain the primary `join` condition. The rest of the conditions can go on the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->join(
    'predict',
    "(predict.id_predict = portion.id_predict AND `event`.`id_event` = 5)",
    'left'
);
```

are you looking for this ?

**EDIT**

```
$this->db->join('predict', "predict.id_predict = portion.id_predict", 'left');
$this->db->where('event.id_event = 5');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use two time

> $this->db->join(......);
>   
>   $this->db->join(......);

for multiple joins through active records.